# Error de cambios Git

Tags: git, github, git-push

Buenas tardes me parece este error no se porque
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

subi cambios y me aparece asi [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta? Y cuál es el error? Simplemente git te dice que hay un fichero que has modificado, pero no lo has añadido al repositorio local con lo que el git push no tiene cambios que subir al remoto.

Answer (score 0):

Los pasos que yo sigo para hacer el commit son

1. git status (para ver la modificaciones)
2. git add . (para añadir todas las modificaciones antes del commit)
3. git commit -m"comentario" (comentar lo que voy a subir)
4. git push origin miRama (puede ser el nombre de tu rama o al master)

En lo que estas haciendo faltaría hacer el paso 2 y 3 por lo que te manda error.

Comment: `git add . ` no es muy recomendable, pues te añade **todos** los ficheros de la carpeta actual y recursivamente todos los de todas las subcarpetas que contiene. A menos que tengas un `.gitignore` muy bien pensado, puedes acabar con montones de basura o incluso material "sensible" (contraseñas) en el repositorio. Es mejor añadir individualmente los ficheros que realmente quieras tener bajo control de versiones, o en todo caso `git add -u`  para los que ya estaban bajo control y fueron modificados.

Answer (score 0):

No es un error, te esta diciendo que en tu Genesis.java local tienes cambios que no están subidos en el control de versiones de git. Al hacer push , estas intentando subir al remoto unos cambios que no tienes en tu control de versiones, por eso te dice que está todo actualizado.

Propongo:

```
git add src/com/vespot/Genesis.java

git commit -m "comentario sobre el cambio"

git push
```

Un saludo !

Answer (score 0):

Intenta hacer

```
git add src/com/vespot/Genesis.java
```

Luego haces

```
git commit -m 'La razón de tu cambio'
```

luego

```
git pull origin turama
```

y para finalizar

```
git push origin turama
```

Espero te sirva

Comment: me sirvio mucho gracias , sino que me di cuenta que no coloque el add mucha hueva yo aveces pasa cuando me saturo de cosas